# Disable expand on tree after doubleclick

Tags: java, tree, swt

I'm using SWT for our gui. We are using Tree to get a tree menu. Now we want following behavior:
- When double clicked on the parent -> open screen, no expand/collapse of the tree
- When using the arrow (on the left of the parent item) -> expand/collapse the tree

Currently when doubleclicking on the parent item will open the screen and expand the tree. After some Googling I found some solutions but when I implement those I can open the screen without expanding the tree. But cannot expand the tree in another way.

For opening the screen from the parent I use this handler:

```
operationMenu.addListener(SWT.MouseDoubleClick, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        }
};
```

How can we implement this in SWT?

Urls that I have use:
[SWT: prevent Tree from expanding by doubleclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006888/swt-prevent-tree-from-expanding-by-doubleclick)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "solution" you found when googling? I assume it uses a mouse listener and prevents the event.

Comment: Haven't tried, but you could try to add selection/click listeners and then do event.doit = false. That usually blocks events from happening.

Comment: event.doit = false does not work. My doubleclick handler is called later then the event for collapsing/expanding.